# WSO2 MSMQ setup

Tags: wso2, msmq

I want to use msmq transport in wso2 esb. My wso2 esb is install on an linux os.
   Is it possible to use wso2 esb run on an linux os or I must run wso2 esb on an windows os to make msmq work ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can run WSO2 ESB on Linux and connect to a MSMQ running on Windows. You'd need the MSMQ Axis2 JAR in the ESB dropins folder and you're good to go.

See the MSMQ transport doc here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/MSMQ+Transport